# Where can I put i18n messages when using Struts2 annotation validations?

Tags: java, struts2, internationalization

I'd want to use [annotation validators](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/xwork-core/apidocs/index.html?com/opensymphony/xwork2/validator/annotations/package-summary.html) provided by Struts2 in form

```
@RequiredStringValidator(key="required")
```

Where can I put properties file that will be looked up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I18N messages/resources can go in a variety of locations depending on where they'll be used.

Resources are looked up hierarchically, starting with action-specific property files, package files, eventually in the global properties defined with the resource property in the other answer.

XML configuration is the preferred mechanism, however, if you decide to explicitly name resources.

See the [S2 Localization docs for additional details](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/localization.html).

Answer (score 0):

In your Struts.properties insert the following;

```
struts.customs.i18n.resources=MyResources
```

And create a file called MyResources.properties to be resided in the same path as the Struts.properties and have your key/value based messages in that file